# How do I generate OpenAPI documentation for an Isolated Framework4.8 Azure Function (v4)

Tags: azure-functions, openapi, .net-4.8

I have had no luck generating OpenAPI in my Azure Function.

It calls a SOAP web service, so has to run in Framework 4.8, as the non-Framework versions of .NET don't return the entire nested XML payload. I've tried Functions v1 and v4 (Isolated), and have not been able to generate OpenAPI.

What am I missing?

There are a number of error with the below attribute block. The main one is `'OpenApiOperation' is not an attribute class`

Start of Function.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using TGAWebSvcs;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using System.Linq;
using TGAWebSvcs.TCSvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;

namespace TGAFunction
{
    public static class GetData
    {

        [Function("GetServerTime")]
        [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "GetServerTime", tags: new[] { "TGA API" }, Summary = "Retrieve server time", Description = "This API returns the current server time")]
        [OpenApiParameter(name: "username", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Description = "The **username** parameter")]
        [OpenApiParameter(name: "password", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Required = true, Type = typeof(string), Description = "The **password** parameter")]
        [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "The operation completed successfully")]
        [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(string), Description = "The operation was not completed successfully")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> GetServerTime([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequestData req) //, ILogger logger)
        {
...
```

Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FunctionsDebugger.Enable();

        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker => worker.UseNewtonsoftJson())
            .ConfigureOpenApi()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you've been tried, any error you got?

Comment: You can import your function API in the APIM Instance and from there, you can generate Open API according to your requirements.

Comment: I've tried APIM, and that doesn't help. It doesn't recognise my parameters or return data format. I'm trying to use the Function in a Logic App, which should be able to read the OpenAPI directly from the Function, if I can work out how to generate it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

This works for .net8 Isolated Azure Function app.
Make sure your project has these references:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.5.1" />
<ItemGroup/>
```

and these using statements

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes;
```

This works and produces a swagger page for me:

```cs
[Function(nameof(CreateUser))]
[OpenApiOperation(operationId: nameof(CreateUser), tags: new[] { "Create User" }, Summary = "Create User", Description = "Create User")]
[OpenApiRequestBody(contentType: ContentTypes.ApplicationJson, bodyType: typeof(UserRequest), Required = true, Description = "UserRequest")]
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.Created, contentType: ContentTypes.ApplicationJson, bodyType: typeof(UserResponse), Summary = "User Response", Description = "UserRequest Response")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> CreateUser(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, HttpMethodNames.Post, Route = UserRoutes.UserRoute)]
    HttpRequestData req,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
...
```

Not sure why, but instead of
`using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi;`, it worked for me with `using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes;`

Hope this works for you!